# Radio Boxes not resetting to "checked" status in Firefox

Tags: html, forms, firefox, radio-button

I'm lost as to why my radio box form isn't working in Firefox 7.0.1, but works fine in IE, Chrome and Safari.  The problem is that the radio boxes which are "checked" aren't resetting to what the HTML shows.

For example, if I change the temperature setting from "f" to "c" and and press Select, the action script sees the correct values.  I then press Back in FF and refresh the window, "c" is still selected.  As stated, this works as expected in other browsers, but not in FF.

I'm having a hard time believing that something this basic is broken in FF, but the HTML is straight forward.

-- Geoff

```
    <form name="form1" method="POST" action="weather_uom_set.php">        
    <h3>Precipitation</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="precip" value="in" checked="checked"/> Inches (")<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="precip" value="mm" /> Millimeters (mm)<br/>
    <h3>Temperature</h3>
    <input type="radio" name="temp" value="f" checked="checked"/> Fahrenheit (&deg;f)<br/>
    <input type="radio" name="temp" value="c" /> Celsius (&deg;c)<br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: I posted a fix that works for me over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988729/firefox-remembering-radio-buttons-incorrectly/31680722#31680722

Answer (score 1):

It may be because Firefox is remembering the previous form submission values, which can override any default choices you've defined in your HTML. Also, even though you haven't stated it here, I'd like to point out that Javascript can also override default HTML behavior as well, so if you do have a script running, make sure it also isn't setting/overriding a default value.

Comment: Yes, it will be Firefox preserving the state of the form between refreshes. Hit enter in the location bar to load a fresh version.

Comment: Quentin's answer was correct. I had assumed that pressing the reload symbol on the URL bar and/or pressing F5 would have reloaded the page.  However, placing the cursor in the URL bar and hitting enter did the trick.   Things that you never knew!  I will say that this is NOT very intuitive.

Comment: @GeoffSchultz A normal reload is supposed to reload the page while preserving as much state as possible (e.g. scroll position).  You can do a force-reload by holding Shift while clicking the reload button or Ctrl while pressing F5 for a full reload.

Comment: This can also happen if you have another form element with the same name in the html form

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this basic is broken in Firefox: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8779735/370290

Answer (score 0):

I originally made the mistake of setting checked=false on the "no" box instead of setting checked="true" on the "yes" box.

However, you might consider a similar fix I came up with to ensure that you get the value you want when the page loads:

```
<input type="radio" name="mybox" id="mybox_yes" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="mybox" id="mybox_no" checked="checked" value="0">

<script>

    var mybox = 0; // value 1 or 0 inserted with server side script

    if(mybox == 1){
        var fix_checkbox = function(){
            document.getElementById("mybox_yes").checked=true;
        };
    }
    else
    {
        var fix_checkbox = function(){
        document.getElementById("mybox_no").checked=true;
        };
    }

    setTimeout(fix_checkbox,1000);

</script>
```

It might be better to do the logic server side then only output the line you want:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("mybox_no").checked=true;},1000);
</script>
```